# Acionar um botão pelo teclado

Tags: javascript, html, teclado

Olá,

dentro do sistema que estou desenvolvendo o usuário pode alterar um cadastro que está no banco de dados. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que ao invés de o usuário conseguir salvar as alterações apenas clicando no botão "alterar" ele consiga fazer isso pelo atalho "ctrl+s" no teclado.

Obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Funciona também em Mac:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
 if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("CTRL+S pressionado!");
 }
}, false);
```

```html
Clique aqui e Pressione CTRL+S (para teste)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript.

- Primeiro reconheça qual será o comando que você deseja utilizar.
- Depois, defina uma function que irá inserir este atalho.
- Por fim, chame a função desejada.

Neste exemplo: Atalho: (Alt + 'a')

```
document.onkeyup=function(e){
  var e = e || window.event; // for IE to cover IEs window event-object
  if(e.altKey && e.which == 65) {
    //Chama sua função JS aqui
  }
}
```

Neste [site](http://keycode.info/) você pode pegar qual o código para cada tecla desejada.